# How to get value of first classname using javascript?

Tags: javascript

How to get value of first classname using javascript ?

I tried to test my code below. but it'll still alert `undefined`.

How can i do that for alert first value of class test (`alert 1`)?

http://jsfiddle.net/3AaAx/104/

```
<div class="test" value="1"></div>
<div class="test" value="2"></div>
<div class="test" value="3"></div>

<script>
var list = document.getElementsByClassName('test');
test_value = list[0].value;
alert(test_value);
</script>
```

Comment: You are calling wrong property. use `className` instead of `value`.

Comment: Do you want the first class name value, so test in your case. Because your question asks one thing but your code is doing another?

Answer (score 4):

`value` is not a property of `div` element. Use `getAttribute` as you are using it as a `ATTRIBUTE` of the element or use `data-*` attributes

```js
var list = document.getElementsByClassName('test');
test_value = list[0].getAttribute('value');
alert(test_value);
```

```html
<div class="test" value="1"></div>
<div class="test" value="2"></div>
<div class="test" value="3"></div>
```

**OR using `data-*` attributes:**

```js
var list = document.getElementsByClassName('test');
test_value = list[0].dataset.value;
alert(test_value);
```

```html
<div class="test" data-value="1"></div>
<div class="test" data-value="2"></div>
<div class="test" data-value="3"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Dear Replace the following code `var test_value = list[0].value;` with `var test_value = list[0].getAttribute("value")`

Answer (score 1):

**Try this,**

```
<div class="test" value="1"></div>
<div class="test" value="2"></div>
<div class="test" value="3"></div>

<script>
    var list = document.getElementsByClassName('test');
    test_value = list[0].getAttribute('value');
    alert(test_value);
</script>
```